# Prononciation de 'lol'

Tags: prononciation, argot, néologismes, internet

Question bête peut-être : comment prononce-t-on 'lol' en français ?
Lol (un seul mot) ou L-O-L (épeler les lettres) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> — C'est écrit « ...c'est une blague lol... » [[\lɔl\](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lol#Fran%C3%A7ais), comme
> [bol](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bol)]
>  — Comment ?
>  — Après *blague* on a L-O-L, dans le
> sens qu'on est [*mort de rire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mdr#Fran%C3%A7ais).

Comment: On prononce "lol", par contre épelle "mdr".

Comment: C'est juste un détail, mais on prononce lol "lol" (acronyme de "laughing out loud"), mais on épelle les lettres "m", "d", "r", qui sont l'acronyme de "mort de rire", qui est l'expression équivalente en français. J'admets que ce serait assez difficile à prononcer. C'est assez rare qu'on prononce un acronyme plutôt que de l'épeler. Mais cela arrive par exemple pour radar (RAdio Detection And Ranging), ou laser (Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation).

Comment: Oui oui, j'ai indiqué  [\lɔl\, comme bol]. Je ne comprends toujours pas vraiment. Si je lisais une phrase comme dans l'exemple de ma réponse, tu dis qu'on répondrait « Après blague on a M-D-R... » ?? @Ben

Comment: Exactement, on pourrait dire que c'est un synonyme de LOL, ou sa traduction en français, mais qu'on le lit toujours M-D-R.